# Authenticate client api endpoint laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, oauth-2.0, laravel-passport

A laravel passport based authenticate system involve 3 apps like,

app1, app2 and appauth(authenticates user/app and endpoints)

this is simple that,
user can get access of authenticate enpoints from app1 to appauth with the api_token.

But, 
What if a user of app2 want to access authenticate endpoint from app1 and the user must be authenticated from appauth.

Comment: what are app1 and app2 here? Is it a separate website?

Comment: Yes. they are several applications.